# Storing result of AJAX in pure Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am learning the basics of AJAX, and I am trying to store the result of the call in a variable. I have a data.txt file with this object:

```
[
{ "id": "5688","name": "  Jorge Luis Borges"},
{ "id": "5799","name": "  Lewis Carroll"}
]
```

And I am calling it with this call:

```
var object = "No object";
function requestFunction(url){
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("GET", url, true);
    request.addEventListener("load", function() {
        object = this.response;
    });
    request.send(null);
    return object;
};
console.log(requestFunction("data.txt"));
```

I don't know why, but `result = this.response` doesn't affect to the variable where I want to store the result, and the console outputs its original value: `No object`.

Any idea why?

---

EDIT: I have been reading the fantastics responses in [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call), and I updated the function to include a callback that, when called, output the result:

```
function requestFunction(url){
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("GET", url, true);
    request.addEventListener("load", function() {
        outputFunction(this.response); // The callback
    });
    request.send(null);
};

// This is the callback
function outputFunction(a){
    console.log(a);
};

requestFunction("data.txt");
```

It works. Now, inside the callback, I want to store the result in a variable, and use it outside the function. Something like:

```
// This is the callback
var storedObject = "Empty";
function outputFunction(a){
    storedObject = a;
    return storedObject;
};
```

But again, it doesn't works. ¿Is because the same reason as the previous code?

Answer (score 0):

```
request.addEventListener("load", function() {
        object = this.response;
    });
```

is called asynchronously

```
object = this.response;
```

would be updated later, your code

```
console.log(requestFunction("data.txt"));
```

doesn't wait for it to finish updating, hence prints the orignal value

Comment: No its not an async function. The function is called asynchronously...

Comment: Yes I see it can lead to misunderstanding, edited

Comment: Ok, checking [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)…

Comment: requestFunction() would have to call a callback or return a promise, you can access the variable once the callback is called or wait for Promise.then()

Comment: Ok, I wrote a callback, but I can't store the value of the object in a variable! I will update the question.